# View animation scale values relative to original

Tags: android, android-animation

I wanted to make a basic animation on a TextView that would shrink when the user tapped it and then scaled back to the original size in order to provide visual feedback. Reading the docs, it seems that there are various ways to animate properties on Android, but I settled for using a view animation, defined in the following XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="true" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">

<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="100"/>

<scale
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="50"/>
```

This works well enough, but it strikes me as odd that I have to calculate by how much I'm going to need to scale the second tag instead of being able to just use values relative to the original. Is there any way to use values relative to the original element (ie, using fromXscale="0.5" and toXscale="1.0") in the second tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right try this

```
tv.animate().scaleXBy(2.0f).scaleYBy(2.0f).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

You can add reverse repeat policy or just add scale back animation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even consider using the reverse repeat to avoid having to do the second animation. That works nicely.